# Check whether a server is online using an IP and Port

Tags: c#

I have two `inputBox`es, IP/Address and Port.

I search a simple code that can check if server (address + port) is online or offline. The result will displayed in e.g. a label (Online/Offline).

The server check can be with a timer or button.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you mean that a "server is online"? Does it mean that the specific `TCP` or `UDP` port is open, that a specific service is working (i.e `HTTPS` over port 1337) - or something else?

Comment: I mean a specified port from an address or IP. It's possible that's from a TCP. It's not a SSL service or similar. Eventually a ping to a address/ip with port or so. If server reachable, the status text is "Online", else "Offline".

Comment: See if this answer can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601133/checking-whether-the-server-is-on-off?rq=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```cs
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
try
{
    tcpClient.Connect("192.168.0.1", 22);
    Console.WriteLine("Port open");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Port closed");
}
```

This snippet will work for testing a server listening to a given IP and port with the TCP protocol.

Futhermore, you could also try to ping the IP:

```cs
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("192.168.0.200");

if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    // Server is alive
}
```

`Ping` class is located in `System.Net.NetworkInformation`.

Comment: Using that exact piece of code i can check if my ftp port is open on my raspbian machine :)  so i don't understand why down voting. After all, i am using the .NET framework and to be honest, it works for me when i want to check my ftp or ssh port status. That's about it.

Comment: Hello, hm, voting was -1 and now 0, I don't know why.
I have a problem, I have to strings (strIP and strPort), strIP is ok, but strPort not, strPort is red underlined. Values are from inputBox'es.

Comment: Connect method takes an integer as the second param. Use int.Parse on your string or to be safe use int port = 0; int.TryParse(strPort, out port);

Comment: Note that the second method utilizing ping will not give dependable results in some real world situations. Servers and firewalls are regularly configured to intentionally not reply to pings.

Comment: I converted the strIP to int32 in a variable, it should be work.

Comment: For **Edit 1**: What is the opposite if server not alive (not IPStatus.Success)?

Comment: You have many options on that enumeration, check only if pingReply.Status != IPStatus.Success and print the status received which of course will be a NOK response.

Comment: OK, I tried. When I press the button, the status was not changed if address or IP was changed in the inputBox. But I see, i need a check for a port, I use the fist code.

Comment: Since `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable`, you need to dipose it by `tcpClient.Dispose();` or put it in a `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer already gets the job done but for completeness the following method **can be used asynchronously and supports timeout**:

```
public async Task<bool> PingHostAndPort(string host, int port, int timeout)
{
    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient()) // TcpClient is IDisposable
    {
        Task connectTask = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port);
        Task timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        // Double await is required to catch the exception.
        Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);
        try
        {
            await completedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (timeoutTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return connectTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && tcpClient.Connected;
    }
}
```

Note that the `timeout` value is in milliseconds. To use the method:

```
bool success = await PingHostAndPort("host", 80, timeout: 3000);
```